# How do I use extends on a class from within same package?

Tags: java, package, extends

I have two .java files inside the path "/utilities/pets/":

/utilities/pets/Animal.java

/utilities/pets/Cat.java

And a Test.java file on top of the path.

In my Animal.java file there's this code:

```
package utilities.pets;

public class Animal implements Cloneable {
  //bunch of private attributes and public constructors and setters-getters
}
```

From Test.java, I can import the Animal class and create Animal instances without any problems, all good til here.

Now I want to make my Cat.java a class that inherits from Animal, but if I type this code inside Cat.java:

```
package utilities.pets;

public class Cat extends Animal {

}
```

The compiler tells me that it couldn't find the symbol Animal
Same happens if I try this

```
package utilities.pets;

public class Cat extends utilities.pets.Animal {

}
```

I don't know how to fix this... help will be much be appreciated.

Comment: `public class Gato extends Animal` is correct.  The real issue is that when you're compiling, you're not picking up the `Animal` class for some reason.  How, exactly, are you trying to build your code? (P.S. if you're not using a modern IDE, I cannot suggest highly enough that you start doing so, as soon as possible, if not sooner).

Comment: Sorry I messed up the names when translating the post (because my code is in spanish actually), just fixed it in the post, but same problem. I'm trying to compile Cat.java via windows command line with "javac Cat.java", as usual. I get this error:

Cat.java:4: error: cannot find symbol
public class Cat extends Animal {
                          ^
  symbol: class Animal
1 error

Comment: What if you use `javac Animal.java Cat.java`?

Comment: That seemed to work, no compiler errors and Cat.class was created, thanks a ton Slaw!

Comment: Note that will compile _both_ `Animal` and `Cat` even if one is already compiled. If you only want to compile a subset of source files which depend on other source files then you must tell `javac` where the other source files are in a way that doesn't cause them to be compiled. See [the tool documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/javac.html), specifically the _Additional Source Files_ section (note the link is for Java 13).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile multiple files via command line you must provide all required `.java` files like:

```
javac Cat.java Animal.java
```

While being in same package you can you the `*` wildcard which will pick up all the required files in current directory:

```
javac *.java
```

In addition for your case, I moved the `Cat` and `Animal` to `model` package and in parent directory I made `Test` class, so the command would look like:

```
javac Test.java model/*.java
```

You can change the `model` accordingly to your needs and the `javac` command is being called in the directory of `Test.java` file.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seemed to work, Cat.class was created, I feel so dumb for not knowing this! Can't thank you enough!!!!

Comment: np, as you probably already saw there's a possibility to use a `*` wildcard within the root directory. While having more packages under root, you can go with `javac *.java model/*.java utils/*.java`. After you're done playing with cmd compiler it's very recommended to jump to some IDE and later take advantage of dependencies managers (Gradle, Maven, etc.)